# javascript regexp, select from certain type of url

Tags: javascript, regex, url, select

I'm making a url filter using javascript

i get a parameter from url

```
parameter 1 = /name/123
//description /text/number
parameter 2 = /name/name/121
//description /text/text/number

var filter = /[/a-z][/][0-9]/;
if(filter.test(page) == true){
  //do code;
}
```

I made it to select a parameter 1, however it selects parameter 2 too.

what should I fix to select the only parameter 1 or parameter 2 separately?

Thank you.

Comment: the **pattern** you use is invalid, it matches only **one character** followed by `/` followed by **one digit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filter = /^\/[^/]+\/\d+$/;
// or
var filter = /^\/[a-z]+\/\d+$/i;
```

That is to say that you can match on:

```
^       beginning of string
\/      a / (escaped for the regex literal)
[^/]+   one or more non-slash characters in a row, or
[a-z]+  one or more letters in a row
\/      another slash
\d+     one or more digits
$       end of string
```

Note also that your `if` test doesn't need the `==true` part, you can just say:

```
if(filter.test(page)){
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you use is invalid, it matches only `one character` followed by `/` followed by `one digit`.

Try using this pattern:

**PATTERN**

```
/^\/[a-z]+?\/\d+$/
```

**INPUT**

```
1. /name/name/121
2. /name/123
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1. false
2. true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly modified nnnnnn's version by the addition of a quantifier : `(this pattern){n times}` which gives `/^(\/[^/]+){n}\/\d+$/`. See [nnnnnn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20370831/1636522) for more details.

```
function createRegex(n) {
    return new RegExp(
        '^(\\/[^/]+){' + n + '}\\/\\d+$'
    );
}

var twoParts = createRegex(2);
twoParts.test('/part1/part2/123'); // true
twoParts.test('/part1/part2/part3/123'); // false
```

To split the url into multiple parts :

```
var parts = '/part1/part2/123'.match(/[^/]+/g);
var part1 = parts[0]; // "part1"
var part2 = parts[1]; // "part2"
var part3 = parts[2]; // "123"
```

Be careful though, `match` returns `null` in case of failure.